# Is there an easy Cailburn.Micro way to display a new Window/Dialog?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dialog, caliburn.micro

I've been following a Winforms tutorial and converting it to WPF and MVVM using Caliburn.Micro. However, within winforms tutorial, it calls a new form.

```
CreatePrizeForm frm = new CreatePrizeForm();
frm.Show;
```

I thought I could use Caliburn.Micro ActivateItem to do a similar thing. I have included some code of my experiment.

My ShellViewModel

```
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<object>
{
    public void LoadFormOne()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You are about to activate FirstChildViewModel");
        ActivateItem(new FirstChildViewModel());
    }

    public void LoadFormTwo()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You are about to activate SecondChildViewModel");
        ActivateItem(new SecondChildViewModel());
    }
}
```

My Shellview

```
<Window x:Class="ConductorTest.ShellView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ConductorTest"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="ShellViewModel" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"  x:Name="LoadFormOne" Content="Load Form One" />
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3"  x:Name="LoadFormTwo" Content="Load Form Two" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

A ChildViewModel

```
    public class FirstChildViewModel : Screen
    {
        public FirstChildViewModel()
        {
        }
    }
```

A ChildView

```
<Window x:Class="ConductorTest.FirstChildView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ConductorTest"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="FirstChildView" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <TextBlock>You are now in First Child View</TextBlock>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

So my thinking was, if I click LoadFormOne button, it would execute,

```
ActivateItem(new FirstChildViewModel());
```

which would then new up a FirstChildViewModel(), which like the

```
DisplayRootViewFor<ShellViewModel>();
```

in the standard bootstrapper.cs, would then fire up a new WPF form.

But obviously not.

What am I missing or doesn't Caliburn.Micro provide an easy way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: It has a window manager. check that out https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/window-manager

Comment: deleted comment

Answer (score 2):

There is a `IWindowManager` interface for that purpose.

```
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<object> {
    private readonly IWindowManager window;

    public ShellViewModel(IWindowManager window) {
        this.window = window;
    }    

    public void LoadFormOne() {
        MessageBox.Show("You are about to activate FirstChildViewModel");
        var model = new FirstChildViewModel();
        ActivateItem(model);
        window.ShowDialog(model);
        //or
        //window.ShowWindow(model); //For non-modal
        DeactivateItem(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Nkosi, Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, but as added, the code doesn't compile. But thank you again for pointing me in the right direction as I was stuck as to the direction to look at next.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Nkosi for pointing me in the right direction; after looking at his answer I came across this link https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/Caliburn.Micro/WindowManager/ShowDialog/php-windowmanager-showdialog-method-examples.html

And then I modified my code to work.

```
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<object>
{
    private readonly IWindowManager window = new WindowManager();

    public void LoadFormOne()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You are about to activate FirstChildViewModel");
        var model = new FirstChildViewModel();
        ActivateItem(model);
        window.ShowDialog(model);
        //or
        //window.ShowWindow(model); //For non-modal
        bool CloseItemAfterDeactivating = true;
        DeactivateItem(model, CloseItemAfterDeactivating);
    }
}
```

Points to note

1. In Bootstrapper.cs you cannot have

   ```
   DisplayRootViewFor<ShellViewModel(new WindowManager())>();
   ```

to send in a new WindowManager into ShellViewModel, so you cannot have a constructor for ShellViewModel to accept a WindowManager. So I changed 'window' to private that gets initialised on ShellViewModel startup.

2. You cannot have

   DeactivateItem(model);

The compiler complains you need a second parameter "**close**: Indicates whether or not to close the item after deactivating it.". I have changed the code to have the second parameter.

I hope this helps someone else in the future.